# What are the differences between those two types of cluster api endpoint here?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-namespace

There are two types of scope resources.

- Cluster scoped resources
- Namespace-scoped resources. 
  I know the basic differences between those. But in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/) they mentioned the same API endpoint for both resources.
  [image]

What are the differences here as both endpoints look like same?

Answer (score 1):

It's just telling you, that it returns you ALL resources of this type over ALL namespaces, even if the scope of your resource type is namespaced.

Comment: Sometimes you would like to know, in which namespace a specific resource is. So you can request namespaced resources over all namespaces.